# How do family conflicts and childhood experiences influence passive-aggressive behaviours in the workplace?

Tags: developmental-psychology, personality, io-psychology

Possibly related but not a duplicate - ["How does the personality of a successful leader influence the development of his children?"](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/how-does-the-personality-of-a-successful-leader-influence-the-development-of-his)

Workplace behaviours and personality traits, e.g. passive-aggressive behaviours, can be highly influenced by family conflicts and childhood experiences. Blanch and Aluja (2009) distinguish between work interfering with family (WIF) and family interfering with work (FIW):

> Work–family conﬂict (WFC) has become an important dimension in the
>   study of individual differences at work. This concept has been deﬁned
>   as a form of inter-role conﬂict in which the role pressures from work
>   and family are mutually incompatible, identifying at least three types
>   of WFC: time, strain and behaviour based conﬂict (Greenhaus & Beutell,
>   1985). Two main directions are generally considered in WFC research:
>   work interfering with family (WIF), and family interfering with work
>   (FIW) (Frone, Russell, & Cooper, 1992).

Conflicts in the family environment may contribute to passive-aggressive behaviours in the workplace. Rejection at home can influence personality traits of the individual (Rohner, 1980):

> The rejected child is especially likely to become hostile, aggressive,
>   or passive-aggressive if  rejection takes the form of parental
>   hostility.

Organisations cannot function optimally if its employees exhibit passive-aggressive behaviours that are a result of past or current family conflicts. These behaviours can have an impact on culture as well (Forbes, 2013). Passive-aggressive behaviours are becoming common in the workplace and I'm interested to know what are the antecedents of passive-aggressive behaviours in the workplace that arise from family conflicts and past childhood experiences.

**Questions**

- What are the antecedents for passive-aggressive behaviours in the workplace that are influenced by past or current family conflicts and early childhood experiences? And are there any supporting studies describing this link?

**References**

- Blanch, A. & Aluja, A. (2009). Work, family and personality: A study of work–family conﬂict. Personality and Individual Differences, 49, 520-524
- Rohner, R.P. & Rohner, E.C. (1980). Antecedents and consequences of parental rejection: A theory of emotional abuse. Child Abuse and Neglect, 4, 189-198
- Forbes. (2013). "Passive-Aggressive Behavior Will Destroy a Company's Culture", http://www.forbes.com/sites/amyanderson/2013/03/06/passive-aggressive-behavior-will-destroy-a-companys-culture/